# How to annotate queryset with number of common IDs in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've got following models:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=24)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=24)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(to=Ingredient)
```

and a list with valid Ingredients IDs, like for example:

```
ing_id_list = ['5d481cf3abe2d800150de7b6', '5c8c05bee3f3391eda4320b2', ...]
```

I'm stuck in building a queryset with an annotated field that enriches recipes with the number of common related Ingredients IDs and the IDs in the list:

```
annotated_recipe_queryset = Recipe.objects.annotate(no_of_common_ings=Count(##PLEASE HELP##))
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Django>=1.8 you can use Conditional aggregation. For your example the query could be:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField
annotated_recipe_queryset = Recipe.objects.annotate(
        no_of_common_ings=Count(Case(When(
            ingredients__id__in=ing_id_list, then=1), output_field=IntegerField(), )))
```